How to join two subnets (on different interfaces) into one network managed by ISP router
I am very new with Linux networking. I have the following network topology:

I have WiFi router connected to ISP. "Host 1" and Debian 12 server are connected to the router (and Internet) via WiFi. WiFi connection on Debian server uses 'wlo1' interface configured to have static IP address. Here is it's NetworkManager config:

Debian server has the second ethernet interface 'enp2s0' to which the "Host 2" is connected. I created the following bridge in NetworkManager:

And added to the bridge ethernet connection based on 'enp2s0' interface:

Now I have "Network 2" subnet 10.42.0.0/24. The "Host 2" automatically got IP address 10.42.0.139. Here is the output of 'nmcli connection' command:

From inside Debian server I can successfully ping all devices in "Network 1" and in "Network 2".
But I can not ping "Host 2" from "Host 1" and vice versa. So my task is how to configure Debian server to make devices in "Network 2" visible to devices in "Network 1" and vice versa.
Ideally I want that "Network 2" to be managed by WiFi router to have the IP addresses 192.168.1.0/24. In other words I want to join "Network 1" and "Network 2" into a single network managed by WiFi router.
How can I do that?

For this you have 2 options: 1.) Configure network 2 to obtain DHCP address that are in the same subnet as network 1, or 2.  Insert a second network card in wlo1 and connect host 1 to wlo1.  Configure the 2nd nic to accept requests from the IP Address Range in Network 2, i.e., NIC 1 sends requests from to and from network 1 and NIC 2 sends traffic to and from NIC 2 to network 2.  If network 1 needs to speak to a host in 2 it will pass through bridge 2, after you add the 2nd NIC to bridge 2

For reachability, just add route for "the other network" on the host(s) of both networks.
On Host 1 (and friends), add the route 10.42.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.102.
On Host 2 (and friends), add the route 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.42.0.1. (It is assumed that br2 is configured with the IP 10.42.0.1.)
Make sure IP forwarding is enabled (see the net.ipv4.ip_forward sysctl) on the Debian server, and that its firewall (iptables and/or nftables) does not forbid the desired communication.
Note though if you need stuff that involves broadcast or multicast to work (such as service / device discovery whatsoever), routing mentioned above is not going to help. As you may or may not already know, you can't really use a WiFi station (client) as a bridge slave / port, so you'll have to resort to e.g. a tap VPN or multicast forwarding / relaying whatsoever (if that's a thing).
